# Downloading images using src in python produces empty images

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My script is kind of working but the files it saves are empty. Any ideas? Forgive me for all the unused import at the top! I tried a lot of different things to do this. In here I'm pulling the img using selenium. The SRCs are then iterated through a loop and transformed into bytes so that they can be written using os.path. I suspect the website is protecting itself against such scraping maybe?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import os
import urllib
import urllib3
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import requests


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://superrare.com/features/the-intersection-of-machine-and-artist")
time.sleep(2)                                                                                                            

#the element with longest height on page
ele=driver.find_element("xpath", '//div[@id="root"]')
total_height = ele.size["height"]+8000
time.sleep(2)  
driver.set_window_size(1920, total_height) 
time.sleep(2)



imgsrc2 = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//img")))

time.sleep(5)
download_folder = "/Users/rcastong/Desktop/imgs"
if not os.path.exists(download_folder):
    os.makedirs(download_folder)

for i in imgsrc2:
    imgsrc = i.get_attribute("src")
    str_img = str.encode(imgsrc)
    with open(os.path.join(download_folder, os.path.basename(imgsrc)), "wb") as f:
        f.write(str_img)
```

Comment: if `src` is link to image then you CAN'T download it using `str.encode()` but you need `requests.get(src)` - but I don'ty see `requests.get(src)` in your code.

Comment: if `src` is image as string `BASE64` then you will need module `base64` to convert it back to image bytes.

Comment: `src` can be relative url and you may need to add `https://superrare.com/...` to use absolute link. You could use `print()` to see what you have in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use `requests` to get data from server

```
    response = requests.get(img_src)
    data = response.content
    
    with open(fullname, "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

---

Minimal working example.

It works for me for few first images. Maybe other images need longer `sleep()` or it needs to scroll to the bottom to load all `src` by JavaScript.

```
import os
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://superrare.com/features/the-intersection-of-machine-and-artist")
time.sleep(2)                                                                                                            

#the element with longest height on page
root = driver.find_element("xpath", '//div[@id="root"]')
total_height = root.size["height"] + 8000
print('total_height:', total_height)
time.sleep(2)

driver.set_window_size(1920, total_height) 
time.sleep(2)

imgs = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//img")))
time.sleep(5)

print('len(imgs):', len(imgs))

download_folder = "/Users/rcastong/Desktop/imgs"

# it will create only if not exists
os.makedirs(download_folder, exist_ok=True)

for number, item in enumerate(imgs, 1):
    print('---', number, '---')

    img_src = item.get_attribute("src")
    print('from:', img_src)

    fullname = os.path.join(download_folder, os.path.basename(img_src))
    print('  to:', fullname)
    
    response = requests.get(img_src)
    data = response.content
    
    with open(fullname, "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: Thx very much for this @furas. I tried it and it does indeed work! You are probably right about the imgs that it ignores.